# Getting the stack trace or current file from Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I want to make a logging mechanism that also includes the file that the log statement was written from.

So for instance, if I have a file:

```
//foo.js
log("stuff");
```

Then I want the `log` function to be able to include the file name `"foo.js"` in the logs.

Is this possible? I haven't been able to find anything about it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger a new error and catch it internally. That way, you can access the stack trace using `myError.stack`, which will print a list of files that have led to your execution point. Example:

```
try {
    throw new Error('Trace!');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.trace);
}
```

If you have more questions, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could throw the error and handle it in the `uncaughtException` event. Note that this should only be done for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from triggering a new error, one other possible solution is to create and maintain your own global array that contains the name of all the controller you have opened.